# Reason behind diurnal tides

Tags: tides, moon

I know that an area has a *diurnal tidal* cycle if it experiences one high and one low tide every lunar day. Many areas in the Gulf of Mexico experience these types of tides. I read that:

> Diurnal tides occur due to a series of factors, among which
> continental interference and the Earth's spin axis are the most
> important to be considered.

But I don't understand of Earth's tilt affect some ares like the the Gulf of Mexico and don't affect similar places like the Gulf of Oman or the Gulf of Aden